# How to upload a image to firebase storage using react native and expo?

Tags: firebase, image-uploading, firebase-storage, react-native-ios, expo

I am trying to set a profile pic and upload it to the firebase storage in my ios app using react native. I am using the following code to upload the image:-

```
  _pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3]
    });

    this.setState({ image: result.uri });
    console.log(result);

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      this.setState({ image: result.uri });
    }

    let localUri = result.uri;
    let filename = localUri.split("/").pop();

    // Infer the type of the image
    let match = /\.(\w+)$/.exec(filename);
    let type = match ? `image/${match[1]}` : `image`;

    // Upload the image using the fetch and FormData APIs
    let formData = new FormData();
    // Assume "photo" is the name of the form field the server expects
    formData.append("photo", { uri: localUri, name: filename, type });

    return await fetch(
      "SERVER_URL",
      {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
        header: {
          "content-type": "multipart/form-data"
        }
      }
    );
  };
```

I have set the rules for firebase storage as follows:-

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

But no images get uploaded to the folder and I get no errors. Any help or suggestion is appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: Hi, if you don’t mind using cloudinary, I show how to upload and then get the uploaded url to save to firebase
https://medium.com/@ifeoluwaking24/how-to-upload-an-image-in-expo-react-native-to-firebase-using-cloudinary-24aac981c87

Also you can try it snack but make sure you add your cloud_name and upload_preset
https://snack.expo.io/@ifeking/upload-to-cloudinary

Comment: It's now fully supported after releasing SDK 26 See this example
https://github.com/expo/firebase-storage-upload-example/blob/master/App.js

Comment: @AwadHaj can you please take a look at https://github.com/expo/firebase-storage-upload-example/issues/14 ?